# How to get public Ipv6 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ipv6

I am using nodejs to get ipv4 like

```
app.get('/getip', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
    });
});
```

this work fine for ipv4 but i need to get ipv6 too how can i get public ip of router family ipv6.

I'm using node 7.6.0

Comment: You will have at least a link-local IPv6 address, and maybe one or more global and/or ULA addresses on your interface. IPv6 is not like IPv4 that may be using NAPT with private/public addressing that gets translated on a router or firewall.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't get an IPv4 or IPv6 address. It gets the value of the X-Forwarded-For header provided by some frontend server in front of your application. If that server doesn't accept an IPv6 connection, there will be no IPv6 address.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code to fetch User's IPv6 Remote address**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({
    ip: req.ip || req.connection.remoteAddress || 'null',
}));

const listenServer = () => {
    console.log('App running on');
};

// Use IPv4 address to listen on IPv4
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', listenServer);

// Use IPv6 address to listen on IPv6.
app.listen(3000, '2401:4900:169e:80c3:11e9:63ba:1f81:d224', listenServer);
```